# How to get virtual keyboard on raspbian for raspberry pi zero?

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero

Raspbian does not have a virtual keyboard, at least not reachable by the start menu. I only have a mouse and I want to control my raspberry pi zero, type some commands. What is the easiest way to get virtual keyboard working on it?

Remember: rpi zero does not have wifi so I cannot install things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download `matchbox-keyboard` and `matchbox-keyboard-im` packages ([link](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/matchbox-keyboard/) for Raspbian, if you have Buster, you need `.deb` files version 0.2 dated `28-Jun-2020`). Write installation commands in a text file, e.g.:

```
cd /boot
sudo dpkg -i matchbox*
<- don't forget the newline after the last command
```

Put the packages and the text file on the FAT partition of the SD card (on the Pi, this will become the `/boot` folder), plug the card your Pi zero, open the text file with a text editor, and then copy the commands in a terminal window. If you copy a command with the newline character, it gets executed automatically when you paste it.

I don't recommend `florence`, in my experience this keyboard performs poorly in many scenarios.

Comment: I finally tried this, and this is what I got: https://imgur.com/a/CwbzPJS. Do you know what's happening?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Looks like you're installing a package which is already installed. If you don't have a working keyboard by now, I recommend you remove both matchbox related packages and install them again from scratch.

Comment: How should I start this keyboard then? It's not on accessories and I cannot type commands on terminal to see

Answer (score 2):

I tried two different ones: `matchbox-keyboard` and `florence`.

You will need a connected USB keyboard to be able to try them. Otherwise, use an SSH connection.

Open a "Terminal" and type `sudo apt install matchbox-keyboard`. You will find it installed under "Accessories" with the name "Keyboard".

In my opinion, `florence` is better and more intuitive, but it depends on the `at-spi2-core` package to work properly, or it will hang on first "keystroke".

Try it with `sudo apt install florence at-spi2-core`. You will find it installed under "Universal Access" with the name "Florence Virtual Keyboard".

Comment: But I can't install things on it because it has no wifi

Comment: cheap wifi dongle will fix that - because to add something you need to install it

Comment: Nice hint about `at-spi2-core`, small correction though: `florence` doesn't depend on it (check out the package [dependencies](https://packages.debian.org/buster/florence)), and that's probably the root cause of the problem. Not having the necessary package listed as a dependency is essentially a bug, and I'm convinced it's not the only one, that's why I don't recommend Florence.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't make it work with the answer here, but I did:

```
sleep 30; sudo apt-get install -y matchbox
```

as you see, I had 30 seconds to take off the usb keyboard to put the usb ethernet adapter so it could install matchbox

then run

```
matchbox-keyboard
```

for some reason all the usb hubs I tried wouldn't work so I could not use keyboard + ethernet adaptar at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Same method as Dmitry's answer, but I recommend trying out [Onboard](https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/o/onboard/) which is more useable than matchbox and florence IMO.

Not associated with Onboard, just want more visiblity for other options