# How to install .deb of virtual keyboard on rpi zero (no internet)

Tags: pi-zero, keyboard, debian, bash

I'm following this answer: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/121642/74564 on how to install a virtual keyboard on rpi zero without internet access.

```
cd /boot
sudo dpkg -i matchbox*
<- don't forget the newline after the last command
```

When I've ran these commands on the terminal using the mouse, with files from here: http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/matchbox-keyboard/, I got this:

[image]

What should I modify in the script so it works?

Comment: Don't post illegible pictures of text post text.

Comment: @Milliways I don't have a keyboard neither internet on the rpi

Comment: If you can run code on the Pi you can capture output!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get virtual keyboard on raspbian for raspberry pi zero?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/121600/how-to-get-virtual-keyboard-on-raspbian-for-raspberry-pi-zero)

Comment: @Dougie this is where I came from